# Convert short array to signed byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, byte, primitive

As input I'm getting a `short` array like {20, 250, 12, 255}. 
I need to convert it to byte[] {20,-6,12,-1}
I tried to use ByteBuffer:

```
    short[] data = {20, 250, 12, 255};     
    ByteBuffer dbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length*2);
    dbuf.asShortBuffer().put(data);
    byte[] array = dbuf.array();
```

But the output formatted as:
{0,20,0,-6,0,12,0,-1}
How to get signed byte array like {20,-6,12,-1}?

Comment: `byte` in Java is signed.  There's no such thing as a byte value of 255.

Comment: Simplest is to just loop through the values and assign from the short array to the byte array with a `(byte)` cast.  Creating a ByteBuffer will be slower, more obscure, and more error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply use byte[] which is signed because byte in java is singed. There is no need to convert to short if you want output like that.

---

Below is just conversion mechanism if you cant.

Loop over the array and do a down cast.

```
    short[] data = { 20, 250, 12, 255 };
    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (short i : data) {
        bytes[count++] = (byte)i;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Output:

```
[20, -6, 12, -1]
```